# Using user defined function withing Update query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good day!

I've used my user-defined function within an update statement in the following way:

```
UPDATE Users 
SET 
    CurrentLevel = [dbo].[GetCurrentLevel](id),     
            Rate = [dbo].[GetRate](id),
      LastUpdate = GETUTCDATE()
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

And it gives me the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

I always get only 1 value whenever I execute these functions outside this Update query.
The following code works as expected

```
DECLARE id_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR  
SELECT id FROM Users 
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
OPEN id_cursor;    
  
FETCH NEXT FROM id_cursor  
INTO @id
  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @rate FLOAT = [dbo].[GetRate](@id);
    UPDATE Users 
    SET 
        CurrentLevel = [dbo].[GetCurrentLevel](@id),        
                Rate = @rate,
        LastUpdate = GETUTCDATE()
    WHERE id = @id
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM id_cursor  
    INTO @id
END
```

I do not understand why am I forced to use a cursor and update 1 row at time.

UPDATE.
This is not a trigger, but a stored procedure.
The user defined-functions both have return type FLOAT, which means that can not return multiple values by definition. Function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRate]
(
    @userID int
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @discount INT = (SELECT TOP 1 [BonusSize] FROM Bonuses WHERE userID = @userID);

    DECLARE @rate FLOAT = (SELECT SUM(s.Level * (i.Bonus + @discount))
                           FROM [Stats] s 
                           JOIN [Orders] v 
                           ON s.Level > 0 AND s.id = v.id AND v.userID = @userID
                           JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(ISNULL(Bonus,0)) as Bonus FROM Items GROUP BY id) i
                           ON i.id = v.id)

    RETURN ISNULL(@rate/86400.0, 0);
END
```

Comment: one of your function returns more than one row for sure !

Comment: Or you have a very poorly written `TRIGGER` on your table.

Comment: We have no idea what your functions are doing, but one of them, or both, are returning more than 1 row.

Comment: @Stu those functions *can't* return more than one run; they are scalar functions. By definition they return a scalar value.

Comment: Almost certainly a badly written trigger, please add it to your question. Side note: I'd recommend an inline Table Function, much more performant

Comment: @Larnu it's still possible for a function to [try](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3708872e77c4521ab97612c28ecb8a5a) and return more than 1 value

Comment: Without the definition of the trigger, we cannot reproduce this error. I suggest, however, you have a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers) and you are almost certainly assuming (in your `TRIGGER`) that an `UPDATE` (or DML statement) can only ever effect one row, and your SQL above clearly disproves that.

Comment: Though true, @Stu , (I didn't say that a scalar function couldn't try to return multiple rows and fail) if that were the case in the above the second attempt, with the `CURSOR`, would fail too. The fact that it does not effectively evidences that the problem is when the OP is trying to `UPDATE` multiple rows; which is almost certainly due to a poorly written `TRIGGER`.

Comment: Yes I do concur. Probably the OP could confirm by `alter table Users disable trigger all` and trying the function again.

Comment: Cursor fetches one at a time inside the loop. and when you execute it outside the function, due to in clause it returns multiple values. so it gives you an error. If you can show us a sample of data and after update, expected result, helpers can have a try to provide a better solution.